# app crashes with cursor.getInt()

Tags: java, android-studio

I have this method:

```
 public String givenCheckmark(String name, String date)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = Cache.openDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select value from checkmarks where timestamp ='"+date+"' and habit ='"+name+"'", null);

    String habitValue = "";
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if (!(cursor == null)) {
        habitValue = Integer.toString(cursor.getInt(0));
    }

    cursor.close();
    return habitValue;
}
```

for some reason if i delete the

```
habitValue = Integer.toString(cursor.getInt(0));
```

the app does not crash. so the problem must be in the cursor.getInt(0). The query returns only one line. I am guessing the cursor is not in the first line but...why??

Comment: What error do you get on the compiler?

Comment: I am sorry i forget to say that. The compiler does not show error. But the app crash

Comment: Check to see if your Cursor.getInt(0) is NULL. my guess would be that your database is not returning a value.

Comment: You should use the return value from cursor.moveToFirst() to check if there is anything in the cursor. this probably will not help but you should do it anyways.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely reason is the item at index "0" is not an Integer. Another reason is the Cursor itself may be empty.  Finally, you probably have to check if there is actually a value returned.

To address the first part, you need to use `Cursor#getColumnIndex()` to get the index of the column you're trying to retrieve.  So if it's an "id" you want, then you would do:

`int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));`

To address the second part, you need to ensure that there were results returned.  To do that, you just check `Cursor#getCount()`. So:

`boolean isEmpty = cursor.getCount() == 0;`

Alternatively, the return value for `Cursor#moveToFirst()` will actually return `false` if the cursor is empty meaning you can retrieve values by using something like this:

```
if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
   // The cursor is not null and contains elements.  Continue retrieving values.
}
```

For the third part, you can use `Cursor#isNull()` to check if there is a value at the given index.  So something like this:

`boolean doesNotHaveValue = cursor.isNull(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));`

Other problems I see here is you're checking if the cursor is null *after you move it to the first index* meaning that you'll get a `NullPointerException` regardless of wether or not the cursor was null.  You're also closing the cursor regardless of whether or not it is null.

Comment: i do not understand the difference between the second and third part. Also it is surely an integer

Comment: A cursor points to a specific row.  "getCount()" tells you how many rows there are.  If there are no rows, then there were no results.  "isNull()" tells you if a specific index (column) of the current row is null.

Comment: And I see that you're only getting the "value" column from the table, so that's fine since that's going to be the only thing returned.  Typically when you do queries though, you have many rows and many columns and there isn't a guarantee in which order they appear.

Comment: ok i get it. Moreover in the first part you are telling me to delete the select value .. part and replace it with cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id")); ?

Comment: "id" is a hypothetical column name for a table.  In you're case you would use "value" because that is the name of the column of your table. It's not necessary in this case since you're only querying for "value".  You do need to check "getCount" and "isNull" though.

Comment: i tried and cursor.getCount()==0 is true and with cursor2.isNull(cursor2.getColumnIndex("value") it crashed

Comment: Check the LogCat for the actual Exception. It'll tell you precisely why.

Comment: Well, that's something you're going to have to get acquainted to if you want to develop on Android because you'll be spending a lot of time looking at it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I figured that the problem is inside sql statement. but i dont know what. because when i changed with something more simple 
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select value from checkmarks ", null); it hasnt crashed